# Как изменить язык ошибок с русского на английский?

Tags: postgresql

Как изменить язык ошибок с русского на английский?

А то русским кириллицу выводит в ошибках.

Answer (score 2):

Используемая при выводе ошибок локаль задаётся настройкой `lc_messages`:

```
postgres=# select 1/0;
ОШИБКА:  деление на ноль
postgres=# set lc_messages to 'C';
SET
postgres=# select 1/0;
ERROR:  division by zero
```

Настройку имеет возможность менять суперпользователь, глобально в файле конфигурации, для пользователей или БД через `alter user ...` и `alter database ...` соответственно, или для себя в настройках сессии.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой. Решение нашел здесь: [ссылка](https://iu5bmstu.ru/index.php/PostgreSQL_-_%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_psql_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4_Windows)!

В решении версии ПО: MS Windows 7 SP1 x64, PostgreSQL 8.4.12 x32, но у меня Windows 10 x64, PostgreSQL 12 и тоже сработало.

[image: Я вот сделал]